# What should I take into account to implement a CarPlay enabled iOS app?

Tags: ios, carplay

I'd like an iOS app I'm developing to be compatible with `Apple CarPlay`. I've never done it before and, as far as I understood, it is needed to fill in a [form](https://developer.apple.com/carplay/) to request the possibility of your app to be supported by `CarPlay`. However, I don't find further information regarding this process:

1. Should you apply for `CarPlay` support for an already finished product? Or can you apply for it for a product you are about to start or you are still developing?
2. What exactly happens once you send the form? Does `Apple` decide if you can support `CarPlay` and, if so, then you have to do something?
3. What things would you have to take into account in your app before applying for `CarPlay` support?
4. What considerations/changes would you have to make to your app if it is granted `CarPlay` support?

I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to write/integrate app to display on Car Play? Any updates after iOS 9?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1):

You've started at the right way, by looking at the requirments and licensing. This is not trivial, as you probably already figured out.

Basically put, the developer program that allows you to create Carplay apps is [Apple's MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). You can apply for enrollment, but it has some pretty high requirements. For example, your company has to either be a "mass production" manufacturer of hard/software or contracted by such a manufacturer.

Being an app development company alone is not enough.

If you want further details, I've added a longer answer in the SO question: "[Is iOS CarPlay API Public? How to Integrate CarPlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541642/1039247)".