# Can I make an iPhone app to be included in the CarPlay with developer version (without Apple official approval)?

Tags: ios, carplay

I am sorry that I look around but didn't find answer for this. I am new to ios development and want to create an app and include it in CarPlay to test it. I don't want the app to be public now, just for testing. So is there any developer version I can use? Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to use an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If the accessory(Car audio system) supports iOS app for CarPlay, it must setup at least one, but preferably many,SupportedExternalAccessoryProtocol parameters in their IdentificationInformation message

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 12, many CarPlay APIs are public. Once you add the respective entitlements, you can develop a CarPlay app even without Apple's blessing. See [How to test an iOS application on the CarPlay simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526509/how-to-test-an-ios-application-on-the-carplay-simulator) for more details.