# Is it possible to design for CarPlay with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, carplay

I have been playing around with SwiftUI since the beta launched and was curious if anyone has figured out way to design for CarPlay in Xcode using SwiftUI? It doesn't seem to be available in Apple's list of devices and so far I haven't been able to find a way to enable it as a secondary screen.

Currently using Xcode 11 Beta 5. Tried seeing if CarPlay could be added as a .previewDevice, but that is specifically for hardware.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You won't be able to see CarPlay in `Xcode` because it's only for people who are enrolled with Apple `MFi Program.` This gives you access to the tools, documentation, technical specs and the license itself to develop for CarPlay. Please see [here for the MFI program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) and here for the [MFI FAQ](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action).

A very good write up on StackOverflow can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372095/is-ios-carplay-api-public-how-to-integrate-carplay).

It is also currently unknown if CarPlay can be developed with `SwiftuI` because people who develop CarPlay apps need to sign a NDA. But I think Apple will continue to push SwiftUI so I don't see why it's not possible

Answer (score 6):

You don't need MFi for CarPlay, you need CarPlay entitlement.
Still not sure about SwiftUI and CarPlay.
I am sure SwiftUI will not support some specific CarPlay categories such as Media Playback and Messaging & VoIP, but maybe with Navigation or Automaker.